# How do I get the output from a pl/sql procedure with a SYS_REFCURSOR for output in TOAD?

Tags: stored-procedures

The following procedure exists in an application and works correctly.  I need to execute this procedure in TOAD.  Note:  I am new to PS/Sql and Toad.  I have tried variations of the following but keep getting the "Invalid Sql Statement" error message in Toad.  I tried var, variable, Declare, Sys_Refcursor, Refcursor, ...

```
var x_out SYS_REFCURSOR
EXEC mySchema.myPkg.myProcedure('NV', 401334, :x_out)
print :x_out
```

what is the way (or a way) to do this in TOAD?

Comment: Does it work if you put BEGIN ... END; around it?

Comment: You could try putting semicolons at the end of each line, except after BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

You can't just print out a SYS_REFCURSOR, you'll have to loop through it.  You'll have to adapt code below with your own variables.  I'm not sure how many columns you have coming into your cursor; I show two columns below.

```
DECLARE
    x_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_col1 VARCHAR2(255);  --You may also have to declare a different data type depending on what is returned in the columns.
    v_col2 VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
EXEC mySchema.myPkg.myProcedure('NV', 401334, x_out);
LOOP
    FETCH x_out INTO v_col1, v_col2;
    EXIT WHEN x_out%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('Column1: '||v_col1||' Column2: '||v_col2)
END;
```

TOAD might also want you to add `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` at the very beginning (no semicolon after it, I think)

Comment: I tried the suggested technique, and I post my "actual" code with the error message I received

Comment: In TOAD, you should be able to find the procedure, mySchema.myPkg.myProcedure, and generate or modify (or at least *view*) the code behind the procedure.  That would give you clues about what input the procedure is expecting, and what its output is.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I tweaked this a little bit, and now it works.  Here is my code that works correctly:

```
DECLARE
x_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
col1 number;
col2 VARCHAR2(255);
col3 VARCHAR2(255);
col4 Date;
col5 VARCHAR2(255);
col6 VARCHAR2(255);
col7 number;
col8 number;
col9 number;
col10 number;

BEGIN
DDTMS.PKG_ADMIN.GETPROCESSACTIONS('NV', 401334, x_out);

LOOP
    FETCH x_out INTO col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('co1_1: '||col1||' col_2: '||col2||'co1_3: '||col3||' col_4: '||col4||' co1_5: '||col5||' col_6: '||col6||'    co1_7: '||col7||' col_8: '||col8||' co1_9: '||col9||' col_10: '||col10);
EXIT WHEN x_out%NOTFOUND;    

END LOOP;


END;
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  If my answer was in any way helpful, I would appreciate an upvote.